# Track the very first boot of Android Devices

Tags: android, web-apps, software-development

Looking for an Android APK that keeps track of the device's very first boot.

**Recommendations:**
1- Log the very first boot to a log file.
2- Upload the log to server.
3- Keep the log after factory reset (if possible)
4- Has an option to reset the counter
5- Sync the Date & Time with UTC.

**Edit**: The goal is to know when the end-user has used the device for the  first time.

Comment: I doubt that such an app exists, but the task basically could be achieved by a simple script utilizing the `dmesg` and `logcat` (or the `bugreport`) utils, redirecting output to a file, uploading it, and on success renaming/deleting itself to not be executed on the next boot. Remaining question is how to auto-launch that on-boot. There might be apps for that part, though – and the approach depends on whether the device is rooted or not.

Comment: @izzy : Thank you for the quick reply; as you commented it is not feasible, but is there something else to do ?

Comment: Which is why I made it a comment only: I was afraid of that. Sorry to read nevertheless. Hopefully, with the "keywords" in mind, you can find something coming closer to your needs. Fingers crossed, good luck!